# How to install gensim and run package in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, gensim, word2vec

i want to do in python 3.7.4:

and getting this Error:

i already tried:

using `conda` and `pip`

using local windows and windows server

multiple reinstallments of diffenent versions of packages (e.g. `numpy` and `scipy`)

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:/Users/Administrator/Documents/GitHub/contract-criteria-identifier-on-aws/schnelltest.py", line 1, in 
>       import gensim
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim__init__.py", line 5, in 
>       from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\parsing__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from .preprocessing import (remove_stopwords, strip_punctuation, strip_punctuation2,  # noqa:F401
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\parsing\preprocessing.py", line 42, in 
>       from gensim import utils
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 40, in 
>       import scipy.sparse
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse__init__.py", line 230, in 
>       from .csr import *
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 13, in 
>       from ._sparsetools import (csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks,
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>   PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\contract-criteria-identifier-on-aws> & C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Administrator/Documents/GitHub/contract-criteria-identifier-on-aws/schnelltest.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:/Users/Administrator/Documents/GitHub/contract-criteria-identifier-on-aws/schnelltest.py", line 1, in 
>       import gensim
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim__init__.py", line 5, in 
>       from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\parsing__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from .preprocessing import (remove_stopwords, strip_punctuation, strip_punctuation2,  # noqa:F401
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\parsing\preprocessing.py", line 42, in 
>       from gensim import utils
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 40, in 
>       import scipy.sparse
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse__init__.py", line 230, in 
>       from .csr import *
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 13, in 
>       from ._sparsetools import (csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks,
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Try to add python to your system path, and then try install it using pip

Comment: I see `DLL` in error - mayb it needs C/C++ libraries which you have to install manually.

Comment: @furas what do you recommend to do to fix the issue, if the problem are some c/c++ libs?

Answer (score 0):

That error is actually suggesting some problem in `scipy`'s installation – that's the source of the actual line of code where the `DLL load failed` error arises. You should try:

(1) uninstalling & reinstalling `conda`

(2) ensuring you've activated a "conda environment"

(3) manually conda-installing individually required packages, like `scipy`, and watching the output carefully for any warnings/errors

(4) when finally running your code, still ensuring you've activated the right conda environment

If you still have problems, expand your question with more specific details about how each part was installed, and whether there was reported success or failure at each step.

Notably, `conda` is usually very helpful in getting these packages working under Windows. But in general, they all get the most development, use, and quality-attention under more Unix/Linux-like systems. So if you have the option to *not use Windows*, everything may have a better chance of working, and when you hit problems, you'll have a larger body of prior docs/help to draw upon. (It all can still be made to work on Windows, but often requires using secondary or less-preferred installation/configuration options.)

Comment: i tried the code to run on two different ec2 instances: One with conda one without conda (only installed the packages that were needed with pip). Still doenst work. now im reinstalling conda on an ec2 instance. I also dont thnk it is a path issue.

Comment: You would need to expand your question with the exact commands you ran, and verbatim output/errors you saw for each step tried, for me or other potential answerers to understand how and why it "doesn't work" for you.